# Error when using DanfoJS in React Native: Property 'document' doesn't exist

Tags: react-native

I tried to use danfojs in react native app but I got this error:

> Android Bundled 7632ms (E:\omdtf\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js)  ERROR
> ReferenceError: Property 'document' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can
> happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
import ManagerScreen from "./components/ManagerScreem";
import { readCSV } from "danfojs";

let customFonts = {
    "Roboto-Black" : require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf'),
    "Roboto-Bold" : require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'),
    "Roboto-Medium" : require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf")
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    
    state = {
        fontsLoaded: false,
    }

    async _loadFontsAsync() {
        await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
        this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
      }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this._loadFontsAsync();
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <ManagerScreen />
        )
    }
}
```

It allows you to filter and sort according to telephone numbers

**excelFile.js**

```
import { readExcel } from 'danfojs';

//const dataFrame = require('danfojs');

export default function excelFile(fileUri){

    const data = []
    const erreur = null

    readExcel(
        `${fileUri}`,usecols=[1,6,11,13,14]
    ).then( df => {
        df.colums = ["dateOp","status","telephone","envoi", "retour"]
        df = df[df["status"] == "Succès"]

        const groupeData = df.groupby(['dateOp','telephone']).aggregate({"mntEnvoi":"sum","mntRetour":"sum"}).to_dict()
        const envoiDict = groupeData['envoi']
        const retourDict = groupeData['retour']
        envoiDict.map((obj) => {
            data.push([
                obj[0],
                obj[1],
                envoiDict[obj],
                retourDict[obj]
            ])
        })
        return data
    }).catch(
        (err) => {erreur = err}
    )

};
```

Comment: Can you share your index.js file ?

Comment: It doesn't help to beg. It _does_ help to take the time to format your question well so it's more readable.